# How to count degrees of freedom

Tags: classical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

I am able to visualize and see that $y=A \sin{x}$ has 1 degree of freedom, because $z=0$ and $y$ depends on $x$. However, its plot looks like a 2D plane, even though according to the DOF it is a 1D motion. Or am I just missing some point in it? Also if any of $x$, $y$ or $z$ depends on another one of them, then it is not a freedom for that particle to move freely in it, right?

Comment: You have three degrees of freedom and two constraints $z=0$ and $y-A\sin(x)=0$ thus you obtain  one generalized coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A particle that can move in three dimensions have $3$ degrees of freedom since we need a three-coordinate, say $(x,y,z)$, to specify the position of the particle in physical space.

Since you are given a constraint $y=\sin(x)$, You can eliminate one of the degrees of freedom and thus you have two degrees of freedom. The coordinate of the particle are $(x,\sin(x),z)$ , As you can see there are value of two variable needed to specify the position of the particle in physical space.

Comment: This would be the answer if the particle were constrained to move along a particular surface, in which case the motion is 2DOF.

Answer (score 1):

If a particle is constrained to move along the curve you described, it is one DOF because you only need one coordinate to describe the configuration of the particle. The easiest way to see this is to use the arc length along the curve as the parameter for locating the particle. Give me the arc length $s$ and I can tell you where the particle is:
[image]

Another way to think about it is if you give me $x$, I can also tell where the particle is. It is at $(x,A \sin(x), 0)$, as another author explained.

A particle moving along a helix is also 1DOF motion, despite the helix being a space curve that occupies 3D space. You gave me an example involving a plane curve.